# Change 110 outlet to 220

Tags: dryer, 120-240v, rewire

I’d like to move my clothes dryer.  It requires a 220 plug.  I used to have a whirlpool bathtub that was on its own 110 outlet.  Can I convert the existing 110 outlet to a 220 outlet with needing to run new romax?

Comment: depends, does the new dryer need a neutral?

Comment: What size wire fed the tub and what is the requirement of the dryer?  The tub is probably at 20A on #12 wire (30A 125V circuits are theoretically possible but rare and it would be a bit crazy to sell a tub that uses one).    The dryer is probably 30A needing #10 wire (almost all dryers are).  So statistically you probably cannot.

Comment: Yes, anyway a safe modern dryer connection needs a 4-wire cable and socket and plug; if you're still on 3-prong now is the time to modernize that.  All it takes for the 3-prong dryers to kill you is one loose connection on one wire.  That's a condition we call "fail deadly", where an ordinary expected failure will kill you.  Nothing else in modern electrical is like that.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely. Electric dryers generally require 240V/30A circuits, to get enough power for drying. That requires #10 wire (in copper). On the other hand, 120V circuits are very rare above 20A. So the wire you have is most likely #12 (in copper), unsuitable for a 30A circuit.

In addition, the existing 120V/20A circuit is likely only two wires (hot/neutral) plus ground. An electric dryer will most likely require three wires (hot/hot/neutral) plus ground.